# Combine multiple views on pinch zoom and replace them with a different View

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-canvas, pinchzoom

I have a subclass of HorizontalScrollView(parent) which is managing multiple child views inside it. Each View consists of a rectangle, few lines below it and TextView(See image). I have added pinch zoom gesture in it so when user pinch zoom all the child views which are between the two fingers are scaled according to scale factor. So for example my first finger is on Jan and second finger on March and I am doing pinch in, all three views (Jan,Feb and March) are scaling. I am scaling only in x direction. Also I have defined minimum and maximum width of a particular view.

Now I want to extend this feature. I want to include some kind of hierarchic feature in it. So if all the views in a particular hierarchy are in minimum width and if I try to further scale them down(by pinch zoom), then all these views must be replaced by a different View.

For example, say Jan,Feb and March is in one hierarchy and by pinch zoom I scaled down them to their minimum width. If I further try to scale it down, then in place of these three views there comes another View.

The purpose of this feature is that say I have months of a 10 year in HorizontalScrollView. So I have total 120 views(10 years*12 months). So if I scaled down all months of a year and further try to scale them down, then I should replace 12 month views by a year view.

Hopefully I am clear in my question. Can anyone tell me how to do it.

EDIT:
I am storing scale factor of the child views in an array state[] and added two methods in my code

```
     boolean checkstate()
     {
         if(state[6]<=0.3f &&state[7]<=0.3f &&state[8]<=0.3f  )
             return true;
         else
             return false;
     }


    void changewithparent()
    {
        LinearLayout parent=(LinearLayout)takeparent();
        parent.removeViewAt(6);
        parent.removeViewAt(6);
        parent.removeViewAt(6);

        //parent.requestLayout();
        View v=kk.getView(6, null, parent);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        parent.addView(v, 0);
     }
```

Also in ScaleListener I have added the following lines

```
    //start and end are the indices of child views which are scaling
for(int i=start;i<=last;i++)
            {
                LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)pp.getChildAt(i);
                DrawView view=(DrawView)ll.findViewById(R.id.drawview);

                view.mScaleFactor=mScaleFactor;
                view.invalidate();
                state[i]=view.sf;   updating the scale factor in parent by taking the value from child view
                change= checkstate();
                if(change==true)
                    changewithparent();

            }
```

But my application is crashing whenever the minimum limit of child view is reached and I am trying to replace them with parent View

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know how wide your year view will be based on the min width of the months, could you include a year view with it's visibility set to GONE, then swap visibility of the months and Year as needed?

To make it a bit more dynamic, you could have an object for each view which stores it's state, which in this case would include something to tell you if it's at minimum or maximum width. When scaling, you would check each object for state changes. If your state check passes some rule (e.g. 12 month objects at min width, or a 10 year object above max width), you would request a layout which would then replace the views with the appropriate new views, and update your state objects.

Comment: I have to show the summary of all the 12 month view in a year view. So when user collapses all month Views should hide and replaced by year View, which has summary all of 12 months. But in the way you suggested there are two problems:

1) year view size must be summation of month view minimum size.
2) I have to store the yearly view in the beginning itself but its Visibility is GONE. It will deteriorate the performance of scrolling. Also this idea cannot be extend if I have to include one more hierarchy say 10 years summary in a view when consecutive 10 years are in minimum width.

Comment: I don't understand how 1 is a problem. You said you set minimum width for each view, so you know what that *12 is.
For point 2, views that are set to GONE are not computed as part of the layout, so it won't slow anything down.

Comment: Say my *12 is somewhat large size and I want the year View to be smaller than this size

Comment: I expanded on the answer to make it more dynamic.

Comment: The reason I suggested that the year view is the min width for the months *12 is so that it would be the same width as what it replaces and there are no jumps. It could of course be any width you want.

Comment: Hey whenever I am trying to replace child views with a new parent which is parent of these views. But in the meantime application is crashing. Can you help me and check if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I don't think you can assign a new parent to a view that already has a parent. But I don't understand why you would want to do that anyway.

Comment: Its not the actual parent I want to assign but a new view instead of old views when a threshold is crossed. Please see the code in the question.  I have try to do it but application is crashing as soon as i call addview in parent

Comment: Hi @anakin78z

Can you please help me on this problem. Last time your help was very helpful.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054181/listview-animation-on-item-addition-not-working-properly